# How many child are created by fork() statement in if statements?

Tags: c, process, operating-system, fork

In the following pseudo code, how many child processes are created?

```
fork();
if(fork()==0)
   fork();
fork();
```

I did not quite understand how if statement is executed and how many child of child processes are created within if statements.

Comment: Do you understand what [`fork`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) returns ? Kind of important if you're going to make sense of that `if` condition.

Comment: [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) returns `0` in child process only, so instead of two processes, only one process will run the fork in the branch, other than that it's just visualizing a process tree and counting the leaves.

Comment: assuming we begin with a single process, its 12 in the end. 1->2->4->6->12

Comment: If you want to count the child processes created in the if statement then it is 2 for the conditional and 2 for the body. And over the whole program I count 1 + 2 + 2 + 6 = 11. Fork produces one parent and one child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to see if we can visualise this

Line 1 - fork() generates parent and child_1

Now both of them start running the code

Line 2 - if(fork()==0) is run both in parent and child 1:

1. parent: will generate parent and child_2
2. child_1: will generate child_1 as parent and child_3.

Line 3 - fork() inside if condition, this if condition will be true only for child_2 and child_3, as fork() returns the the id of child when parent is running, and for child id is 0. As child_2 and child_3 are the Childs generated in if condition fork() their id will be 0. After this:

1. child_2: will generate child_2 as parent and child_4.
2. child_3: will generate child_3 as parent and child_5.

After this point we have parent, child_1, child_2, child_3, child_4, child_5 running in parallel.

Now the fork() in Line 4 are run by each of them generating
child_6, child_7, child_8, child_9, child_10, child_11 respectively by each of the running process.

That leads to a total of 12 process out of which 1 is parent and 11 are Child processes.
Hence there are a total of 11 child processes.